# python ceil() and floor() for rounding integer

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a number like

`1.4` and `1.5`

and want to round it.

when using `ceil()`, all the number going to `2` and with `floor()` it's going to `1`

but I want if number `1.5` its going to `2`, and if `1.4` its going to `1`

maybe you guys got my point, sorry for noob question.

Comment: Use the `round()` function..?

Comment: There was always a clue in the phrase "and want to *round* it"

Comment: @donkopotamus yea, searching but didn't find it. english is not my main language so hard to find what is. but I learn a lot now "there always clue", many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the built-in function [`round()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round)

> Return number rounded to ndigits precision after the decimal point. If ndigits is omitted or is None, it returns the nearest integer to its input.

```
round(1.4)
#> 1
round(1.5)
#> 2
```

Comment: nah, thank you. don't know `round` clue is `round()`. now I know there always have clue. :D